Cannot display at 2560x1446 on new computer
I've just bought a new, built computer with a GeForce RTX 4060 display adapter, Windows 11. I'm  trying to use it with a Dell U2711 monitor, but the maximum resolution I'm able to set (with a HDMI 1.4 cable, and others) is 1680x1050, rather than the full 2560x1446.
Any thoughts on why this might be?.. Wisdom hugely appreciated thank you!

Simplest explanation is the cable doesn’t support HDMI 1.4

Thank you.. I bought this cable new this week (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08276MR65?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title - UGREEN HDMI 2.1 Cable 8K 4K 1440P@120/144/165/240Hz 48Gbp) in case this were the problem, does this look an ok spec?..
